# In Some Android Device Wifi turn off Automatically during using Google nearby API

Tags: android, android-wifi, google-nearby

Documentation Regarding Google-Nearby is available here

https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/overview

The Sample Program is given here

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby/tree/master/messages/NearbyDevices

When I run this sample The WIFI get Automatically turn OFF 
How To salve this Problem

Comment: Hmmm. Can you add some logcat output? This should not be happening. Just launch the sample, and copy your logcat output here.

Comment: there are no logcat output as such like error content or else, just plan sample application running and when we click on "Discover nearby devices" Button wifi start on off automatically

Comment: Can you just connect your device to the compute, run `adb logcat` from the shell. Then, create an issue at https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby/issues, adding the logcat output. Without the output, I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: i notice this problem is accrues on the devices version below 5.0